# MSAL-React Admin Consent

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to use the @azure/msal-react to grant authentication to my React application and get a token to query the Graph API. Following the [Microsoft Tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react) I was able to get a User consent.

Some of the functionalities I am implementing requires an Admin Consent. I granted already the consent to the App Registration, but how can I get the token using the Admin Consent?

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin) I need to use a different authorization endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/adminconsent` instead of `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`, but the MSAL configuration I got from the Microsoft Documentation is not letting me change the endpoint, the last part is added by the library:

```js
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/", // This is a URL (e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your tenant ID})
    redirectUri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
  },
  cache: {...},
};
```

Is there a different method I should use? Or how can I manage to get this to work?

Comment: You can also use `prompt=admin_consent` on the authorization URL. Should be possible to define as a parameter.